# How to view turtlesim in Windows host machine using putty?

Tags: ros, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

i am very much new to ROS. I am running one virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Indigo distro installed) using Vmware Player on my Windows 7 host machine. I have connected my vm using putty (ssh client). I tried to run turtlesim via putty terminal and i got the error of 'X server not found' which i have solved using the link [Problem with ROS Networking.](http://answers.ros.org/question/55421/problem-with-ros-networking/). But the output window is coming in the vm. I can control from putty.

My question is, is there any way i can view the output at my windows host machine?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223762/how-to-view-turtlesim-in-windows-host-machine-using-putty?/) by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2016-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have an X-client installed on your Windows machine? If not, that would be the first thing to do.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baila](https://answers.ros.org/users/25509/baila/) on 2016-01-11**:
Thanks a lot gvdhoorm. That solves my problem.